# UITableViewCell not loading label on first time properly

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

My TableViewCell is not loading content in first time after I scrolling up the table it will shows the full view.I have five sections in the tableView only (section =1) got this problem.

I have attached my codes here.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

On load view
[image: On view load]

After Scroll up

[image: After scroll up]

Comment: after set values to cell [tableView reloadData];

Comment: pastie.org/9135727 yes I setup already

Comment: I think that code will not reuse cell.

Comment: Previously it works thats y im not did anything

Comment: change the code the the below answer, then check

Comment: I have 5 sections so I need to add identifier for all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51929/discussion-between-vineesh-tp-and-ios0709)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return 10;
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        return 10;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return 40;
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        return 40;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *View=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,40)];
    View.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:211.0/255.0 green:211.0/255.0 blue:211.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UILabel *lbl_title=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,700,40)];
    lbl_title.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lbl_title.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:20];
    lbl_title.textColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
    if (section == 0)
    {
        lbl_title.text=@"Used";
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        lbl_title.text=@"Expiring";
    }
    [View addSubview:lbl_title];
    [lbl_title release];

    return View;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.section];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl.frame=CGRectMake(180,10, 360, 60);
            lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            lbl.numberOfLines = 3;
            lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18];
            lbl.text = @"";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
            [lbl release];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl.frame=CGRectMake(180,10, 360, 60);
            lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            lbl.numberOfLines = 3;
            lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18];;
            lbl.text = @"";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
            [lbl release];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   cell.textLabel.text = arrayValues[indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}
```